# What is wrong in my "solution"?(task about multiple root,parameter)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I've got this function: $f(x)=x^5-5x^3+5bx+c \in C[x]$.
I need to find parameters b,c so that f will have root with multiplicity 3.
My try in short: I used Horner's method for some $z$,and got 3 equations. Solving these equations I got 3 solutions.

However only the $z,b,c=0$ case is working (I don't know why, in the other cases $z=\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ will not be root with multiplicity 3).
Here is a picture:
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/view/140330/DSC00033_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.jpg

Comment: link appears to be broken.

Comment: it works for me :/ i will try uploading somewhere else

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/yn8ru846l/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$\;\alpha\;$ is a triple root of $\;f\;$ iff $\;f(\alpha)=f'(\alpha)=f''(\alpha)=0\;,\;\;f'''(\alpha)\neq 0\;$  , so it must be

$$\begin{align*}I&\;\;\alpha^5-5\alpha^3+5b\alpha+c&=0\\
II&\;\;5\alpha^4-15\alpha^2+5b&=0\\
III&\;\;20\alpha^3-30\alpha&=0\\
IV&\;\;60\alpha^2-30&\neq0\end{align*}$$

Observe now from equation III that

$$III\implies \alpha(2\alpha^2-3)=0\iff \alpha=0\;\;or\;\;\alpha=\pm\sqrt\frac32\;\ldots$$

Comment: so 0,+/-sqrt(3/2) is ok,but what about the parameters,b and c?

Comment: Well, you still need to make some work by yourself, don't you?

Comment: i wrote 10 instead of 15 somewhere... that was the mistake i guess